# Windows IOT Core self updating applications

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, self-updating

I have developed a basic UWP application that runs some automation for me on my windows iot core raspberry pi 3. Is there a way that I can have the pi update the application running on it by having a self update or accessing the internet? Rather than booting up visual studio and selecting deploy from the build options?

Also if I ever wished to do some form of publishing, like per say create a product that uses the pi and my software, is there a way that I can have the devices update over the users wifi for convenience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, Microsoft is on-the-way.

Some [new offerings](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-announces-two-new-offerings-to-streamline-iot-management/) were added to Azure IoT device management a few months ago, however, there's still in preview.

So one possible approach is to investigate

- Create a custom firmware image with the updated applications/IoT Core.
- Do the firmware update with Azure IoT Hub.

Tutorials can be found in [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-firmware-update/).

Comment: I marked as the answer because this implementations seems valid. Not quite what I am looking for right now. Still a good starting point for windows iot. I don't want to break down my entire project for you, but simply I want the device to indicate myself or other users that an update is available and prompt to update now or later. I'd prefer the device to use some Microsoft server and download the update and reboot running the new software.

Comment: @BaileyMiller did you ever come to a solution?

Comment: tutorial link died alas,. it seems microsoft is on a reorganization spree for iot.

Comment: This may be the updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-node-firmware-update